# how check one check box at one time in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to click on check box at one time. when one check box checked other all check box unchecked.

```js
$('.checkboxes-assign').on('change', function() {
  $('.checkboxes-assign').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class="checker">
        <span class=""><input type="checkbox" name="data[data_id][]" value="21" class="checkboxes-assign">
              </span></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using radio buttons (which function exactly as you want)?

Comment: this is a table format. and when check one check box display assign work field.

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: your code works just fine? https://jsfiddle.net/drr8nfzw/

Comment: Refer this: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/select-only-one-checkbox-at-a-time-using-jqueryexample.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']";
    $(group).attr("checked",false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);
});
```

Comment: No i can't use this. because this is an project requirement

Comment: @Chintan Give it a try

Comment: OP codes are working fine some other factor is affecting the OP code

Comment: try to give particular class to input and then use it